# retrieving all view objects, android

Tags: java, android

I am building a "form validation" method, to see that all EditText objects are not empty.

I want to invoke the same method for each EditText object (in a loop), how can I retreieve them all?

p.s. they are defind in a XML file and not in the .java file, if it matters

Answer (score 1):

You can walk all the children and see if it's in `instanceof EditText`, but I think a better approach would be to have `int[]` of the ids and iterate over that and calling `findViewById()` to get the individual `EditText` instances.

```
int[] editIds = new int[] { R.id.edit1, R.id.edit2, R.id.edit3 };

for (int id : editIds ) {
    MyEditText text = (MyEditText) findViewById(id);
    text.validate();
}
```

Comment: ok, first approach: how do i get a list of all the children?
and second approach: you're saying i should save all id's in this array, regardless of wether they are EditText objects or not? thanks!

Comment: Updated answer with an example of the second approach. If you want to go with the first approach, use `ViewGroup.getChildCount()` and `ViewGroup.getChildAt(index)`. You'll need to do that recursively.

Answer (score 1):

just iterate through all children of your ViewGroup

```
final int count =  parent.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < count ; i++){
    try{
        EditText et = (EditText)parent.getChildAt(i);//this causes exception if view is not EditText

        //perform validation here
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

Comment: If parent.getChildAt(i) returns a view that is an instanceof ViewGroup, you'll want to walk that View's children too. Also, instead of casting and catching the exception, you could conditionally execute that part with `if (parent.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText) { }`